# How to track the the duration of sending data to Google Drive/ Google cloud storage from Google Earth Engine Python API

Tags: google-earth-engine

I am using Google Earth Engine Python API to claculate NDVI and Export the result in Google Drive / Google Cloud storage (bucket). I am using the following code to export data to Cloud

```
task = Export.map.toCloudStorage(
    image = toexport,
    #image = SAVI.visualize({min:0, max:255}),
    description = 'Automation',
    scale = 20,
    bucket = 'gisagnext',
    #fileNamePrefix = 'Automation',
    #path = 'savi/',
    path = 'clip/',
    #path = 'ndvi',
    fileFormat = 'png',
    writePublicTiles = 'true',
    maxZoom = 14,
    minZoom = 4,
    #scale = 20,
    #region = row
    region = geometry1
    #maxPixcels=76904329300
    )
task.start()
```

Now I want to track back the exact time duration of sending data to Google Cloud in Python API.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

You can monitor any batch task by periodically querying the task status. Below is an example, similar to the code in your question.

Setup some example data:

```python
# Define an example image.
my_image = ee.Image("CGIAR/SRTM90_V4")
toexport = my_image.visualize(**{ 'min': 1000, 'max': 3000 })

# Define an export region.
region = ee.Geometry.Point(-112.1401, 36.0589).buffer(10000).bounds()
geometry1 = region.getInfo()['coordinates']
```

Initiate the task:

```python
task = ee.batch.Export.map.toCloudStorage(
  image=toexport,
  region=geometry1,
  description = 'Automation',
  scale = 20,
  bucket = 'my-bucket-name',
  path = 'test_export_map/',
  fileFormat = 'png',
  writePublicTiles = 'true',
)
task.start()
```

Periodically poll the task status, until it is no longer running:

```python
# Monitor the task.
while task.status()['state'] in ['READY', 'RUNNING']:
  print(task.status())
  time.sleep(10)
else:
  print(task.status())
```

For more information, see the Task object's [status method](https://github.com/google/earthengine-api/blob/master/python/ee/batch.py#L75).

Comment: Thanks, but is it possible without tracking?