# Exporting map tiles to bucket fails with "Internal error" in Google Earth Engine, Python API

Tags: python, google-earth-engine

When trying to export an ee.Image using *ee.batch.Export.map.toCloudStorage()* I'm getting an "Internal error" after a while (from 500 to 1000 seconds), regardless of what I try: exporting other assets, changing the scale, setting visualization options...

This is not working:

```py
# Check task status
def status(task):
  start_time = time.time()
  print("Polling each 5 seconds for task id: {}".format(task.id))
  while task.active():
    time.sleep(5)
  if task.status()["state"]=="FAILED":
    print("TASK FAILED: {}".format(task.status()["error_message"]))
    print(task.status())
  else:
    print(task.status()["state"])
  print("Task took %s seconds" % (time.time() - start_time))

# Export tiles
image = ee.Image("users/username/asset")
task = ee.batch.Export.map.toCloudStorage(
    image= image,
    description= "tile-test"
    scale= 20,
    bucket= "name-of-the-bucket"
)
task.start()
status(task)
```

Also I've tried code from an answer found [here](https://gis.stackexchange.com/a/309390/181753). It returns the same error.
**Note:** I have no problems writing to this bucket with ee.batch.Export.image.toCloudStorage(). ACLs are set to "fine-grained" for this bucket.

Is this a problem with my bucket or something else? I've run out of ideas.

Comment: When you consistently receive an “Internal Error” from Earth Engine, please [file a bug report](https://developers.google.com/earth-engine/help#api).

Answer (score 1, accepted):

As suggested by [Kevin Reid](https://gis.stackexchange.com/users/39720/kevin-reid) I filed a bug report and it turns out the task  was failing internally with the following message:

*The member bindings allUsers and allAuthenticatedUsers are not allowed since public access prevention is enforced.*

Which means that the project didn't allow public access to the bucket. **Changing the project permissions solved the issue.**

Comment: Where do you find this message? Is it a response to your report?

Comment: Yes, it is. Since it is an Internal error, messages are not shown to the end user (it seems)

Comment: I was having the same issue. Making the bucket public solved it.